# Get Country/Region name from windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have the screenshot

[image]

and I am intending to retrieve the country which should be "Nigeria". After going through the System.Globalization class, I found the code snippet below

```
System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.EnglishName
```

But I am getting "United States", which is the "Regional Format" from the image above. Is there no way i can retrieve the Country/Region value settings?

Comment: What do you get with RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.DisplayName?

Comment: I get the same result "United States" using RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.DisplayName

Comment: Have you tried testing on actual device?

Comment: i have tried his code on device but he is correct there is property which will reflect the correct country/region ..

Comment: I have tried it on an actual device, still does not give me "Nigeria"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is what i did at the end of the day. First I used the Location API library to get the coordinates(longitude and latitude) of the location

```
        Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
        geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;

        try
        {
            // Request the current position
            Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
                maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
            );

            string latitude = geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.00");
            string longitude = geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.00");                 


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x80004004)
            {
                // the application does not have the right capability or the location master switch is off
                MessageBox.Show("Location is disabled in phone settings.", "Can't Detect Location", MessageBoxButton.OK);

            }
            //else
            {
                // something else happened acquring the location
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

then using google's reverse geolocation to get the information or details of the location based on the longitude and latitude

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=latitiude,longitude&sensor=true
```

i.e if the latitude is 60 and the longitude is 60

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=60,60&sensor=true
```

From the json result, you will be able to retrieve the country's long and short name.

Comment: Damn, that is such a nasty solution. What will happen when someone goes to another country? Then all of a sudden the formatting in his phone is changed lol.

Comment: Get your point Leon, wish Microsoft will come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's old, but maybe someone comes here looking for answer:

```
System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.TwoLetterISORegionName
```

Comment: This only returns the two letter code, e.g. `US` rather than `United States`. Also, the question seems to be about why the OP is not getting the name he expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.` It should correctly reflect the phone language.

Comment: I think he wants to get the region, not the language.

Comment: I have tried System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, this will give me the locale-country code which was en-US. What i want to get is Country/Region value setting which is "Nigeria" from the image i posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.DisplayName;
```

Comment: Still shows "United States", I think the RegionInfo class only shows the Regional Format values not the Country/Region value

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to what the user is asking is this:

```
Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.HomeGeographicRegion
```

This should give you information regarding the *Country/Region* selection in the *language+region* setting.