# Best/fastest way to find current user location on Windows Phone App

Tags: location, windows-phone, globalization

I am trying to figure out what is the fastest way the figure out the current user Country. I know there are a lot of location examples online, my actual is question: since I don't care much about precision, is it OK if I use `RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.DisplayName;` to figure out the user country?

What are the downsides of using this approach (besides precision)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't use RegionInfo.CurrentRegion for that.

For example, I live in Montenegro, but RegionInfo.CurrentRegion on my phone will return USA, which is completely irrelevant being almost 4000 miles away from here.

You have to use `Geolocator` class for that. [Here's some sample code.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17980944/126995)