# How do you get the region settings on a Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to figure out how to get the region settings for the device?  I can find the language and the regional format but not the "country/region"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Country/Region name from windows phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675081/get-country-region-name-from-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CultureInfo

```
 CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

RegionInfo.CurrentRegion
```

Comment: Unfortunately those don't give the "Country/Region" setting...  CurrentCulture gives the "Phone Language" and CurrentRegion gives the "Regional Format" setting

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
RegionInfo.CurrentRegion
```

This will give you the information of Region/Country

Comment: Unfortunately that only gives the "Regional Format" setting not the "Country/Region" setting

Comment: Could you please be more specific what you want other than Country/Region name which is directly available from     RegionInfo.CurrentRegion

Comment: If you go to the phone settings and select "language+region" and I'm trying to get the value for "Country/Region"    RegionInfo.CurrentRegion gives me the value in the "Regional format" setting

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing an UWP app, you should use

```
Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.HomeGeographicRegion
```

Just as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34591175/5717285